# Find index position for given latitude and longitude variables in nc file in python

Tags: python, latitude-longitude, netcdf

I have latitude and longitude variables in nc file, it is a 2d matrix with int32 pixels(pixels), int32 lines(lines), where size- pixels(2325), lines(1589). I need to find a common index position corresponding nearest to the given latitude and longitude in python.

I used the following code

```
import netCDF4
import numpy as np

# Open the netCDF file
nc = netCDF4.Dataset('file.nc', 'r')

# Get the latitude and longitude variables
lat = nc.variables['latitude'][:]
lon = nc.variables['longitude'][:]

# Specify the target latitude and longitude values
target_lat = -22.2830
target_lon = 133.2490

lat_1 = np.abs(lat - target_lat)
lon_1 = np.abs(lon - target_lon)

print(lat_1.shape)
print(lon_1.shape)

lat_idx = np.unravel_index(np.argmin(lat_1), lat_1.shape)
lon_idx = np.unravel_index(np.argmin(lon_1), lon_1.shape)

print(np.unravel_index(np.argmin(lat_1), lat_1.shape))
print(np.unravel_index(np.argmin(lon_1), lon_1.shape))



# Print the line and pixel values for the closest latitude and longitude values
print('Latitude:', lat[lat_idx])
print('Longitude:', lon[lon_idx])
#print('Line:', lat_idx)
#print('Pixel:', lon_idx)


# Close the netCDF file
nc.close()
```

​However, by doing so I am getting sepearate index position for latitude and longitude, I am not sure how to make common intersection for latitude and longitude index postion.

I also tried another way:

```
import netCDF4
import numpy as np

# Open the netCDF file
nc = netCDF4.Dataset('file.nc', 'r')

# Get the latitude and longitude variables
lat = nc.variables['latitude'][:]
lon = nc.variables['longitude'][:]

# Set the target latitude and longitude values
target_lat = -22.5
target_lon = 132.0

# Find the indices of the points with matching latitude and longitude values
lat_idx, lon_idx = np.argwhere((lat == target_lat) & (lon == target_lon))[0]

# Print the line and pixel values
print('Line:', lat_idx)
print('Pixel:', lon_idx)

# Close the netCDF file
nc.close()
```

But this gives me an error.

---> 16 lat_idx, lon_idx = np.argwhere((lat == target_lat) & (lon == target_lon))[0]
17
18 # Print the line and pixel values

IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

Any help in this would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is searching for the exact target value, not for the nearest neighbour... if the value is not in the list it will fail!

```py
lat_idx, lon_idx = np.argwhere((lat == target_lat) & (lon == target_lon))[0]
```

To find the closest value you need to use something like this:
(note that this does NOT check how far away the "nearest neighbor" is

```py
import numpy as np
lon, lat = np.linspace(0, 100, 20), np.linspace(0, 100, 30)
lon, lat = np.meshgrid(lon, lat)

target_lon, target_lat = (10, 20)

lonidx = np.unravel_index(np.argmin(np.abs(lon - target_lon)), lon.shape)[1]
latidx = np.unravel_index(np.argmin(np.abs(lat - target_lat)), lat.shape)[0]

print(f"target: {target_lon, target_lat}, found={lon[latidx, lonidx], lat[latidx, lonidx]} at position {latidx, lonidx}")
```

```
>>> target: (10, 20), found=(10.526315789473685, 20.689655172413794) at position (6, 2)
```

---

Alternatively you might want to have a look at [xarray](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/index.html) for reading NetCDFs...
It provides a `.sel(...)` method that can do the nearest-neighbor lookup for you...

https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.sel.html